# How can I refer to an object that is defined in a javascript for statement?

Tags: javascript, foreach

In Javascript, the equivalent of a "foreach" loop is:

```
for(a in b){
    // b[a] is now one of the elements of the array b
}
```

But is there a way to do this when "b" is defined in the for statement itself?  e.g.

```
for(a in {'a' : 'alpha', 'b' : 'bravo', 'c' : 'charlie'}){
    // can I access the alpha, bravo and charlie values here?
}
```

...

I just realized in writing this that I can use:

```
for(var a in b = {'a' : 'alpha', 'b' : 'bravo', 'c' : 'charlie'}){
    // b[a] will now give me the alpha, bravo, charlie values
}
```

But if I try to declare "b" with:

```
for(var a in var b = {...})
```

I get a syntax error.

This means that I can do it that way, but only by implicitly declaring b as a global.  Is there a way to access those values without creating that global?

I realize that there are other and possibly better ways to do this (e.g. define the array outside of the loop).  I ask out of curiosity if this can work.

Comment: They're "global" anyway; JS has only function and global scope. Unrelated, but that's not an array, it's an object.

Comment: @DaveNewton, if this portion of code is inside a function, `a` will not be global, but `b` will be.

Comment: @DragonRock Sure, but since we have zero context regarding the context of the OP, I commented regarding what was actually in the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton Fair enough.  I assumed the wording "implicitly declaring b as global" was sufficient indication that I was seeking a local within the scope of the loop without getting overly pedantic.

Comment: @JacobEwing There *is* no local "within the scope of the loop", JS doesn't do scoping like that (delta ES6).

Comment: Right, right, ok, so "in the same scope as the loop" would have been better wording in that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification for the `for-in` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) makes it clear that, no, you cannot access the object in the way you wish without having a reference to it in some other variable.

Following the steps through, you can see that the only thing that is known about the object within the statement part of the `for` loop is the name of the next enumerable property, as defined in step 6a:

> Let P be the name of the next property of obj whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is true. If there is no such property, return (normal, V, empty).

To access anything else about the object, you're going to need your own reference to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap it with [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to prevent creating global variables.

```
(function () {
    var b = {'a' : 'alpha', 'b' : 'bravo', 'c' : 'charlie'};
    for(var a in b){
        console.log(b[a]);
    }
})();
```

Comment: The OP is already aware of this option ("*I realize that there are other and possibly better ways to do this (e.g. define the array outside of the loop). I ask out of curiosity if this can work*"). If your answer is, "There is no other way besides declaring `b` outside the loop, as you have suggested in your question," then you should say that.

Comment: It's not like defining array outside of the scope of the loop. If you try to access b after function it will throw error.

Comment: Not outside the *scope of the loop* (i.e., the function that contains the loop statement) but ***outside the loop*** (i.e., the `for` statement itself). The OP is asking if anything can be written strictly inside the parentheses (and possibly brackets) of the `for(...)` statement that would allow access to the right-hand side of the `in` without creating a non-local variable. It looks like your approach here exactly matches the strategy that the OP dismisses in the final paragraph of the question.

Comment: I guess this line _"This means that I can do it that way, but only by implicitly declaring b as a global. Is there a way to access those values without creating that global?"_ confused me a little bit

Comment: @memo, Hm - perhaps I could've been clearer.  I was looking for the equivalent of this PHP snippet:
foreach(array('a' => 'alpha', 'b' => 'bravo', 'c' => 'charlie') as $a => $b){...}